# How can I speed up datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, datagridview

```
var sor in from aracliste in ae.StokAracAra
                                    where aracliste.stok_id == id
                                    join araclar in ae.Arac on aracliste.arac_id equals araclar.arac_id
                                    join modeller in ae.Model on araclar.model_id equals modeller.model_id
                                    join yil in ae.Yil on araclar.yil_id equals yil.yil_id
                                    join motor in ae.Motor on araclar.motor_id equals motor.motor_id
                                    //orderby stok.stok_barkod
                                    select modeller.model_adi + " " + motor.motor_adi + " " + yil.yil_adi + "\n"
```

I get very slow results because my code pulls data from more than 2 tables.
is there any code you can recommend?

Comment: Is it EF core? I would recommend you use EF navigation properties. Than your code can look like this: `IEnumerable<string> adi = context.StokAracAra.Where(it => it.stok_id == id).Select(it.Model.model_adi + " " + it.Motor.moto_adi + " " + it.Yil.yil_adi + "\n"))`.

Comment: When you have to query more than one table, you have to query more than table. To speed up you have to use some special techniques, f.e. I have heard about two: creating indexes for FK; use OLAP cubes.

Answer (score 0):

you can load page by page.

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM 
(
.
.
.
) Table
WHERE RowNumber >= 20
```